# Using the Genderize.io in R

Tags: r, api, httr

I'm trying to figure out a way to utilize the Genderize.io API (http://genderize.io) for a dataset in R. I have a large amount of names to get through in a dataset, so would ultimately like to write a function that would work through my list of names. Unfortunately, this is way beyond my R capabilities. I'm thinking I should use the httr package, but still don't know how to do this after reading through the documentation for the package. I see a lot of packages or sites for using other APIs (Facebook, Twitter), but am unsure how to apply those to this task. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Writing code to "utilize an API" is a very broad request. It's best if you include a very specific example of what data you would use and input and what you would like as output.

Comment: Try the gender package? https://github.com/ropensci/gender

Comment: @MrFlick thank you, I knew it was a vague question but wasn't sure what else was needed. The Genderize.io can provide an output of both gender and probability that it is correct, which is what I am interested in obtaining. Essentially, I have a list of full names (candidates for State Legislatures since 1968) which I have collapsed to just single iterations of first names. I was hoping I could throw that list of names from a dataframe into a for loop to continually access the Genderize.io, creating new variables for gender and probability within the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks @hadley. This package looks like it could work, but I can't even get my R Studio to install devtools.

My code is just: 
install.packages("devtools")

And I get the following response:
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘devtools’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)

I've been searching for solutions to this problem for the past hour...

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure this out using the gender package!